# Python Numbering with list element by for Loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries and there is also an element of comments, how can I print the numbers with comment while printing this list like this ,

1. An example comment
2. Another example comment

here is my code in python

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434', 'comments': []}]

search = input("type your search: ")
        if search in [person['Last Name'] for person in entries]:
            for person in entries:
                if person["Last Name"] == search:
                    print("Here are the records found for your search")
                    for e in person:
                        if e == "comments":
                            for comment in person["comments"]:
                                print(comment)
                        else:
                            print(e, ":", person[e])
        else:
            print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434', 'comments': ['Comment 1','Comment 2']}]

search = input("type your search: ")
if search in [person['Last Name'] for person in entries]:
    for person in entries:
        if person["Last Name"] == search:
            print("Here are the records found for your search")
            for e in person:
                if e == "comments":
                    for index,comment in enumerate(person[e]):
                        print(f"{index+1}. {comment}")
                else:
                    print(e, ":", person[e])
else:
    print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Output:

```
type your search: >? Khan
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Sher
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 2989484
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Ali
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 398439
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Talha
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 3343434
1. Comment 1
2. Comment 2
```

Comment: and what if I get the input from user for example user gives the input 2. and I want to delete the commnet no.2 . ?

Comment: You have to use a separate input statement and a separate loop for that

Comment: You can try doing it by yourself. If you couldn't do it, then you can ask it here or ask it as a separate question so that I can help u.